# Upgrade or Migrate from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2013, 2016, migration, sharepoint-on-prem, upgrade

We have an on-premises SharePoint 2013 and we want to migrate/upgrade it to SharePoint 2016. so which approach we need to follow?  Migrating the farm or upgrading it and why?

Second question, if we have Farm solutions (including Event Receivers) & Sandbox solutions inside SharePoint 2013 will they work as-is inside SharePoint 2016?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off upgrading to SharePoint 2019 or even SharePoint Server Subscription Edition.

[Mainstream support for SharePoint 2016 ended in 2021](https://learn.microsoft.com/lifecycle/products/sharepoint-server-2016) and the extended support ends in 2026.

Comment: the customer might consider this in the future.. my question is about moving from 2013 to 2016 .. and i am asking if  we should consider upgrading or migrating?

Comment: My advice is not to migrate/upgrade to a version of SharePoint that is out of mainstream support. Upgrading between versions of SP is usually better, since database migrations usually have a much higher percentage of success (usually 100%) where as file migrations can involve more errors.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience is always better to migrate. For one particular reason, it will give you a clean slate.

No software product is perfect, and same goes for OS, having a fresh clean install of OS and SP Binaries goes a long way of clearing many small issues that are happening on OS patched over long time.

I tried only one in place upgrade and had a lot of issues, and switched to migration in the end.

Comment: but is doing migration the more standard way? so we do not have to worry about any issues and redeployment of the custom solutions?

Comment: You will always have to worry about custom solutions (and it doesn´t matter if you are doing in place or migration), You will need to either upgrade them or make them work in compatibility mode.

Comment: We are currently migrating large custom solution from SP2013 to SP2019 and it took us 1FTE 2 months to rebuild it.